# Error on Server CI but not locally

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, msbuild, continuous-integration

We have a VB Project that builds fine locally (in all the various configurations), but when it is run on the server is throwing errors relating to unused local variables.

As far as I can see the configurations are the same. This is only using in-project settings, not any of the Stylecop packages, etc.

One difference thats likely is that we run it locally in VS2015 but on the server I believe it uses 2010 still.

**Extract from the .vbProj File**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What is likely to be the culprit for this, and how to I make it break locally in addition to the server?